# Getting error while publishing mvc5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, publishing

I am getting below error while publishing application.

```
 Error 7 Copying file images\Thumbs.db to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\images\Thumbs.db failed. Could not find file 'images\Thumbs.db'.
```

I use this example and publishing same like below url

http://www.compilemode.com/2017/09/publishing-asp-net-mvc-application.html

When i will do publishing the below circle folders are creating in my visual studio with above error, Below is my project root structure

[image]

Comment: Did you check the images folder for thumbs.db as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Check your `images` folder, possibly there exists `Thumbs.db` file reference which included in project but already deleted from corresponding folder.

Comment: I deleted thumbs.db but again same type of error: Error 7 Copying file images\portfolio\fullsize\Thumbs.db to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\images\portfolio\fullsize\Thumbs.db failed. Could not find file 'images\portfolio\fullsize\Thumbs.db'. @PM.

Comment: Thanks all because you people resolve my issue. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio normally exhibits this behaviour when the file in question is referenced in the project but in not existing on the file system.

You can identify such file by looking at the Solution Explorer. They are shown with yellow triangle on the icon of that file.

Expand your Images folder. It should show Thumbs.db with yellow triangle. Right click it and select Delete or Exclude From Project option.

If you believe it should be published, please add it to the respective folder.

Retry publish.